# How to manually connect the 10.1" touch screen 4 pin FFC to raspberry pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, display, touchscreen

I have this [touch screen](https://www.buydisplay.com/default/10-1-inch-1024x600-50-pins-tft-lcd-display-w-touch-panel-and-touch-driver) and I have a universal lcd controller board. However, the controller board doesn't come with a 4 pin touch input. From connecting a 7" raspberry pi screen, is it correct to assume that the 4 pins stand for the same GND, VCC, SDA, SCL and I can just manually connect them to the pi?

Comment: It depends. What does the datasheet say about those pins?

Comment: I found the datasheet a bit complicated.  I could not find any useful references for linux or rpi.  The vendor has instructions for arduino and 8051, but no rpi.  The doc says it is also compatible to rpi. If you can find the demo code for rpi, then we can do something. (1) https://www.buydisplay.com/download/ic/HX8282.pdf
(2) https://www.buydisplay.com/download/ic/HX8696.pdf (3) HX8696+HX8282 Driver IC 8.0 inch TFT LCD Module 
https://tslcd.en.alibaba.com/product/50046288120-806448089/HX8696_HX8282_Driver_IC_8_0_inch_TFT_LCD_Module.html